# MappingException: Unknown entity:hibernate &spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am getting the exception below, and I am not sure what is the reason.

my controller

```
package com.attar.test.controller;

import static 

org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.attar.test.entity.Patient;
import com.attar.test.service.Patientservice;

@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    private Patientservice patientservice;

    @InitBinder
    public void initbinderprocess(WebDataBinder databinder) {
        StringTrimmerEditor trimedit = new StringTrimmerEditor(true);
        databinder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, trimedit);

    }

    @RequestMapping("/frame")
    public String datauser(Model model) {
        Patient theuse = new Patient();
        model.addAttribute("userr", theuse);

        return "user-data";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/userdata", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String datashow(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userr") Patient thesuer, BindingResult bindresult) {

        if (!bindresult.hasErrors()) {
            patientservice.savepatient(thesuer);
            return "show-data";
        } else {
            // return "redirect:/user/frame";
            return "user-data";
        }
    }

}
```

PatientDaoimpl

```
    package com.attar.test.dao;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.attar.test.entity.Patient;

@Repository
public class PatientDaoimpl implements PatientDao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void savepatient(@Valid Patient thesuer) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.save(thesuer);

    }

}
```

PatientServiceimpl

```
package com.attar.test.service;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.attar.test.dao.PatientDao;
import com.attar.test.entity.Patient;

@Service
public class PatientServiceimpl implements Patientservice {
    @Autowired
    private PatientDao patientdao;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void savepatient(@Valid Patient thesuer) {
        patientdao.savepatient(thesuer);

    }
}
```

my patient-entity

```
package com.attar.test.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "patient")
public class Patient {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @NotNull(message = "it is required")
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String first_name;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String last_name;
    @Column(name = "age")
    private Integer age;

    public Patient() {

    }

    public Patient(@NotNull(message = "it is required") String first_name, String last_name, int age) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

WebContent/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        ">



    <!-- <aop:aspectj-autoproxy /> -->
    <!-- Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.attar.test" />

    <!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/patients?useSSL=false" />
        <property name="user" value="dbuser" />
        <property name="password" value="dbpassword" />

        <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.luv2code.springdemo.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />


    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames" value="resources/messages" />

    </bean>

</beans>
```

my error-exception

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.attar.test.entity.Patient

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.attar.test.entity.Patient
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    Root Cause

    org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.attar.test.entity.Patient
        org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.entityPersister(MetamodelImpl.java:620)
        org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1634)
        org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:104)
        org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
        org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
        org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
        org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
        org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
        org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:689)
        org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:681)
        org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:676)
        com.attar.test.dao.PatientDaoimpl.savepatient(PatientDaoimpl.java:20)
        com.attar.test.service.PatientServiceimpl.savepatient(PatientServiceimpl.java:20)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
        org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.savepatient(Unknown Source)
        com.attar.test.controller.Controller.datashow(Controller.java:45)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
        org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.


    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Apache Tomcat/8.5.20
```

I tried to put all lib for spring and hibernate. I don't know what is the cause of the problem.

Comment: I would recommend you review both of these and amend: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You have to adopt the property "packageToScan" in your spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml. It should specify your entity package (com.attar.test.entity).